# TimerTask and AsyncTask execution flow

Tags: android, android-asynctask, timertask

I have a question regarding the exectution of TimerTask, in the following scenario :
I have function called Locate(), and locate has a TimerTask in it, and another function called SendResult which uses AsyncTask to send some data to a server. If I call these functions in the following order:

```
String result = Locate();
SendResult(result);
```

My question is : in this order the result will be sent once Locate() is done, given that locate has a TimerTask, so locate will finish when the timer finishes?

If not then how can I send the result using an AsyncTask once locate is done?

Comment: Why not send the result when the timer expires? So in the TimerTask run method?

Comment: I tried that but it crashed @Byron

Comment: We cannot help you unless you show us your code in that case. What was the error?

Comment: @Byron the exception is " Network on main thread exception"